# If $\sqrt{28x}$ is an integer is $\sqrt{7x}$ always an integer?

Tags: radicals

If $\sqrt{28x}$ is an integer is $\sqrt{7x}$ an integer? I have a book that says no, but I cannot think of an example of the contrary... Not looking for a full proof here just wanting to see a counterexample or logic showing that the book is wrong...

Comment: Notice that $\sqrt{28}=2\sqrt{7}$

Comment: If $2A$ is an integer, is $A$ an integer?

Comment: Just a comment:  You say you want to "check your logic".  But you haven't actually told us what your logic is, other than "I can't think of a counterexample."  In general, "I can't think of a counterexample" is *not* good logic at all.

Comment: mweiss, great point. Sorry for the poor word choice. I've changed the question to better reflect what I mean.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *I cannot think of an example of the contrary* $\dots$ *just wanting to see a counterexample*

Would $~x=\dfrac1{28}~$ satisfy your curiosity ?

Comment: It is outright mind-boggling how my most basic answers are also the ones gathering the most upvotes.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the first part $\sqrt{28 \, x} = \pm n$, $n$ being an integer. Then one finds 
$$x = \frac{n^{2}}{28}.$$
Now consider the second part
$$\sqrt{7 \, x} = \sqrt{ \frac{7 \, n^{2}}{28} } = \sqrt{\frac{n^{2}}{4}} = \pm \frac{n}{2}.$$
This shows that if $n$ is not an even value then the value of $\sqrt{7 \, x}$ is not an integer.

Comment: Presumably you meant to write "an even integer" rather than "an even function", correct?

Comment: Why is it that the positive root of $7x$ can yield a negative number? Wouldn't it just be $\sqrt{7x}=\frac{n}{2}$?

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\sqrt{28x}=\sqrt{4\times 7x}=2\sqrt{7x}$. Can you see what might happen so that $\sqrt{28x}$ is an integer while $\sqrt{7x}$ is not?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose x is an integer.

Then 28 * x is always even, since 28 * x = 2 * 14x.

The square root of an even number, is never an odd number.
(Check that odd * odd = odd)

So if you take examples where x is an integer, sqrt(28x) is never odd, and therefore there exists no counterexample.

So x must be a fraction to find a counterexample, (like 1/28 or 9/28).